# IllegalStateException not caught - why?

Tags: android, exception

Below is my code to show BiometricPrompt to handle IllegalStateException reported by Crashlytics. But it seems exceptions are not caught and crashes are still logged into Crashlytics.

```
try {
        val uiHandler = Handler()
        uiHandler.postDelayed({ myBiometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, mcryptoObject!!) }, 800L)
    } catch (ex: IllegalStateException) {
        onFingerprintRegistrationDenied()
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the try block is emitting `IllegalStateException` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is most likely in your `Runnable` so you should add `try/catch` to that code instead.

Comment: this seems working. Will confirm post app production release. Thanks again.